# Imprimir dados json recebido no post do jquery

Tags: json

estou com a seguinte dúvida, estou fazendo um sistema de calculo de frete o sistema está recebendo uma resposta json no seguinte padrão.

```
{"cServico":
    [{"Codigo":"40010","Valor":"36,90","PrazoEntrega":"3","ValorSemAdicionais":"36,90","ValorMaoPropria"
    :"0,00","ValorAvisoRecebimento":"0,00","ValorValorDeclarado":"0,00","EntregaDomiciliar":"S","EntregaSabado"
    :"S","Erro":"0","MsgErro":{}},{"Codigo":"41106","Valor":"17,80","PrazoEntrega":"6","ValorSemAdicionais"
    :"17,80","ValorMaoPropria":"0,00","ValorAvisoRecebimento":"0,00","ValorValorDeclarado":"0,00","EntregaDomiciliar"
    :"S","EntregaSabado":"N","Erro":"0","MsgErro":{}}
]}
```

como posso estar exibindo essas dados.

```
$('body').append(data);
```

com esse código ele mostra toda a array mais preciso apenas de alguns dados e não estou conseguindo, desde de já muito obrigado.

Comment: Conseguiste pôr isto a funcionar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse JSON tem primeiro que ser convertido em Objeto. Podes fazer isso usando o [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var dados = JSON.parse(data);
```

depois depende como queres usar os dados que tens nessa array da propriedade/chave `cServico`.

Deixo um exemplo com uma tabela:

```
var dados = JSON.parse(data);
var table = document.createElement('table');

// table head
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
Object.keys(dados.cServico[0]).forEach(function (chave) {
    var th = document.createElement('th');
    var tdConteudo = document.createElement('td');
    th.innerHTML = chave;
    tr.appendChild(th);
});
table.appendChild(tr);

// conteudo tabela
dados.cServico.forEach(function (el) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.keys(el).forEach(function (chave) {
        var tdConteudo = document.createElement('td');
        tdConteudo.innerHTML = el[chave];
        tr.appendChild(tdConteudo);
    })
    table.appendChild(tr);
});
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kxL2h17g/

Comment: eu corrigi e mostrou os dados agora vou tentar formatar, desde já muito obrigado

Comment: @ClaytonEduardoMergulhão se a minha resposta resolveu o problema podes marcar como aceite.